# MVC - Make all URLs with a trailing slash 301 to URL without a slash?

Tags: asp.net, routes

Is there a way to redirect all URLs that end in a trailing slash to the url without?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Application_BeginRequest` method in `Global.asax`, add the following:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath != "/" && HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith("/")) {
    string redirect = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    redirect = redirect.Remove(redirect.Length - 1);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    Response.AddHeader("Location", redirect);
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Found my answer here: https://blog.dantup.com/2009/04/reducing-duplicate-content-with-aspnet.html